# Instant Payment Notification (IPN) simulator dose work

Tags: php, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn

IPN delivery failed. Unable to connect to the specified URL. Please verify the URL and try again.

i am trying to use my Paypal ipn simulator but every time it gives me this error message, it seems that ipn simulator cant hit the specified URL, even though i am sure the specified URL is correct. any help please

```
// Connect to database --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----
    require_once ('../config/cart_api.php');

    // bussines email
    $bussines_email = 'tbuss_1358873839_biz@hotmail.com';


// Check to see there are posted variables coming into the script
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") die ("No Post Variables");

// Initialize the $req variable and add CMD key value pair
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
// Read the post from PayPal
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Now Post all of that back to PayPal's server using curl, and validate everything with PayPal
// We will use CURL instead of PHP for this for a more universally operable script (fsockopen has issues on some environments)
$url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
//$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$curl_result=$curl_err='';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Content-Length: " . strlen($req)));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , 0);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
$curl_result = @curl_exec($ch);
$curl_err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$req = str_replace("&", "\n", $req);  // Make it a nice list in case we want to email it to ourselves for reporting

// Check that the result verifies
if (strpos($curl_result, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
    $req .= "\n\nPaypal Verified OK";
    mail("eagleeyes26@hotmail.com", "IPN interaction verified keep going", "$req", "eagleeyes26@hotmail.com" );

} else {
    $req .= "\n\nData NOT verified from Paypal!";
    mail("eagleeyes26@hotmail.com", "IPN interaction not verified", "$req", "eagleeyes26@hotmail.com" );
    exit();
}

/* CHECK THESE 4 THINGS BEFORE PROCESSING THE TRANSACTION, HANDLE THEM AS YOU WISH
1. Make sure that business email returned is your business email
2. Make sure that the transaction�s payment status is �completed�
3. Make sure there are no duplicate txn_id
4. Make sure the payment amount matches what you charge for items. (Defeat Price-Jacking) */

// Check Number 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($bussines_email != $_POST['receiver_email']) 
{
    $message = "Investigate why and how receiver email is wrong. Email = " . $_POST['receiver_email'] . "\n\n\n$req";
    mail("eagleeyes26@hotmail.com", "Receiver Email is incorrect", $message, "From: eagleeyes26@hotmail.com" );
    exit(); // exit script
}

// Check number 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if ($_POST['payment_status'] != "Completed") {
    // Handle how you think you should if a payment is not complete yet, a few scenarios can cause a transaction to be incomplete
}
else 
    {
        $message = "Payment status is completed = " . $_POST['payment_status'] . "\n\n\n$req";
        mail("eagleeyes26@hotmail.com", "Payment status is completed", $message, "From: eagleeyes26@hotmail.com" );
        exit(); // exit script
    }
```

Comment: provide code, what have you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

have you uploaded your files on a free weberver? or free domain? this happened to me, when i tried my ipn script stored on 000webhost, i transfer my files on other webserver, and to my surprise, the ipn simulator sucessfuly sends an ipn to my ipn handler page

Comment: thanks man, yes i am testing this simple shopping cart on free web 000web host server, so you mean i have to move the project to another web server not 000webhost , to get it work......

Comment: i guess so, i bought my own domain and webserver, and uploaded my files there

Comment: but before, i was able to use ipn simulator on 000webhost, i think that was last oct 2012, i dont know what happened after that

Comment: welcome, you can up vote my answer if that really helped, it'll be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Paypal IPN simulator does not work for me. I have used two different servers, logged to an external linux server (in an another country) and wgetting handler urls work fine. Using simulator nothing is received and simulator page prints "IPN Delivery Failed:I/O error: Connection timed out; nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out" after a while.

Handler url is tomcat jsp page, using ip and hostname does not help.

```
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/ipn_simulator
http://111.222.333.444:8080/testing/paypal_IPN.jsp
http://myserver.com:8080/testing/paypal_IPN.jsp
```

If calling paypal_IPN.jsp myself in a browser it calls https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr url with cmd=_notify-validate& param and jsp reads INVALID string reply as was expecting 'cause this was a foodoo transaction anyway.

Test merchant account has IPN enabled, IPN history displayes transactions, tried resending a transaction, all fails. Big showstopper for my Paypal integration test case, cannot go live without able to verify a checkout pipeline.

IPN is enabled in merchant test application but this should not affect IPN simulator anyway. Using POSTFORM classic submit cgibin button goes fine, test visa payment ok, but even then IPN handler url is not invoked. IPN history shows transactions with failed status.

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr